# classic asp/vbscript class to track employees and performance metrics

Tags: class, oop, asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to create a classic asp/vbscript class that will allow me to easily manage a small number of employees (30-40) along with some metrics associated with those employees, about 14 metrics each. I've done some tutorials online and can't quite get how I should proceed. What I have so far is below. It's not much, basically I think I can only add the employees to a dictionary in the class, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
class iagent
    private di_agents
    private ar_metrics
    private pri_agent_counter

    Public function add_agent(uuid)
        di_agents.Add uuid, pri_agent_counter
        pri_agent_counter=pri_agent_counter+1
    end function

    private sub Class_initialize
        pri_agent_counter=1
        dim ar_metrics(14, 5)
        set di_agents = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    end sub

end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you have is just a wrapper around a dictionary. Are you talking about creating a class that represents an employee?

```
Class Employee
  Public Name
  Public Age
  Public Phone
  'other properties
End Class
```

Then you can instantiate Employee like this and set your properties

```
Set e = New Employee
e.Name = "Some name"
```

You could then store your instances of Employee in a dictionary, perhaps paired with an ID:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Call d.Add(uuid, e)
```

However, you're better off using a database for this and using ASP/VBS to extract records... Unless this is just an exercise

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah I am trying to write a page that will calculate and rank the employees based on their performance, and I was trying to find an easier way to store the information between getting it from the DB and the calculation/display phase. I might be headed in the wrong direction here.